# Delayed service call not showing on view

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a service that I call in my `ngOnInit` method. Which returns and fills my array. I then on complete call another service method using the results from the first array which in turn fills a second array.

My problem is that at the time of rendering my second array I assume is still empty so it will never render on to the screen.

Here is a simplified example:

```js
changedBookings: Booking[] = [];
currentBookings: Booking[] = [];

constructor(private bookingService: BookingService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    //Get all changes then filter
    this.bookingService.getAllHistory()
        .subscribe(
            data => {
                this.changedBookings = (data as any).results
            },
            err => {
                console.log(err);
            },
            () => {
                this.getCurrentBookings();
            })
  }

  getCurrentBookings() {
      for(let i of this.changedBookings) {
          this.bookingService.getRoomBooking(i.date,i.level,i.room)
              .subscribe(
                  data => this.currentBookings.push((data as any).results),
                  err => console.log(err),
                  () => {
                    //shows this array being filled
                    console.log(this.currentBookings);
                  }
              )
      }
  }
```

```html
<div class="row">

  <div *ngFor="let booking of changedBookings">
    {{booking.date}}
  </div>

  <!--This one never shows-->
  <div *ngFor="let booking of currentBookings">
    {{booking.date}}
  </div>
  
</div>
```

How can I write this code so I can use both arrays in my html code.

Comment: Updated with fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy fix in the end. But someone else may get caught up.

```
getCurrentBookings() {
  for(let i of this.changedBookings) {
      this.bookingService.getRoomBooking(i.date,i.level,i.room)
          .subscribe(
              data => this.currentBookings.push((data as any).results),
              err => console.log(err),
              () => {
                //shows this array being filled
                console.log(this.currentBookings);
              }
          )
  }
```

}

As this was looping through it was in fact pushing an array of objects at each loop so you end up with something like so:

```
[ [{}],[{}] ]
```

So obviously

```
<div *ngFor="let booking of currentBookings">
  {{booking.date}}
</div>
```

Would be undefined. Easy fix without changing any other code is as follows:

```
<div *ngFor="let booking of currentBookings">
  {{booking[0].date}}
</div>
```